# Regex: Does an XPATH string point to an attribute?

Tags: regex, xpath, attributes

Here's what I'm using: ".+/@[^/]+$". Can you think of a reason why this might not work?

Comment: I think it won't work on `@attr`, which select the "attr" attribute of the context node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a very subtle problem and I think a great question.

My understanding is that an (abbreviated) XPATH points to an attribute if and only its *last* `@` is not within a predicate, that is, something of the form `[...]`, and has no steps after it (something like `/...`).  I think this has the relatively simple regular expression `@[^]/]*$`, that is, there must be an `@` that has no `]`s nor `/`s after it.  Also, if you want to cover unabbreviated XPATHs, you can use `(@|attribute::)[^]/]*$`

I've included a test harness that may prove useful in checking this or other tests.  Note also that there may be whitespace in between tokens which can complicate some regexs.

#### Positive (an attribute)

- `@*` or `@a` or `../@a` or `a/@b`
- `a[@b and @c]/@d`
- `a[b[@c="d"]/e[@f and @g]]/h[@i="j"]/@k`

#### Negative (not an attribute)

- `a[@b]` or `a[@b and @c]`
- `a[b[@c and @d]/@e]`
- `a[b[@c="d"]/e[@f and @g]]/h[@i="j"]/k[5][@l="m"]`

I can't think of a legal example where there is a `/` but not a `]` after the last example, but I think there might be one.

Hopefully these examples make it at least a little clear that there can be arbitrary nesting of `[` and `]` together with `@`s anywhere in between.  Luckily, I think only the very last `@` and its nesting level matters.

(For reference, the OP's regex fails on `@a`.  My original regex failed on `a[@b and @c]`.)

*Edit*: It turns out that there are more corner cases, which convinces me that there is no perfectly-correct regular expression.  For example, once you have an attribute node, there are many ways of keeping it, *e.g.* `//@a//` or `//@a/.` in the abbreviated syntax.  There are also a variety of more creative ways, such as `//@f//[node()]`.  All in all, it seems that if you want to cover these cases, you need to be able to match `[` and `]`, which a basic regular expression cannot do.  On the other hand, you could decide this is too contrived ...

Comment: Oh snap, nice work. These are two perfect edge cases for me to think about. Thanks!

Comment: This is failing for simple cases: `@*[name() != 'foo]` or `@a[ancestor::p]`.

Comment: @Tomalak: You're right, of course.  I stand by my statement that there is in fact no regular expression that works, because it would have to keep track of nesting ...